# Как реализовать отображения и редактирования различных данных в одном стобце модели?

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, делегаты

Есть иерархическая структура данных. Данные хранят в себе переменные разных типов (как стандартные Qt-ые типы, так и кастомные).
С моделью для такой структуры проблем нет. А представление должно быть по типу инспектора объектов в Qt дизайнере. Сложность заключается в том, что нужно в зависимости от типа переменных отображать значения этих переменных (возможно даже кнопки и т.д. вместе с текстом или без) и редактировать их. Во всех книжках и примерах используют делегаты только для определенных столбцов или строк модели. Для столбцов с разными данными можно выкрутиться конструкциями типа if else с проверкой типа у QVariant, что не есть гуд. Нужно, чтобы делегат автоматически отрисовывал значение типа и возвращал нужный редактор. Также нужно, что бы элементы, имеющие потомков, отображались и реагировали на действия пользователя отлично от элементов без потомков.

Нашел [QtPropertyBrowser](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html) (с помощью него сделан инспектор объектов в Qt дизайнере), но он отображает только стандартные Qt-ые типы, в исходниках какой-то ад,  а также по нему нет документации и вообще походу забит болт еще со времен Qt4, ибо версию с гитхаба Qt я скомпилить так и не смог, а получилось скомпилить только версию для Qt4, которую кто-то давным давно портировал под Qt5. Есть еще либа [QtnProperty](https://github.com/lexxmark/QtnProperty), но на нее нет документации, только [статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/217203/) и парочка инструкций на гитхабе. Сборка этой либы у меня получается только статическая, что мне не подходит. Да и мне кажется можно сделать все проще и легче, чем там.

Есть мысля сделать делегат с фабрикой редакторов и рисовальщиков для различных типов данных(Что-то типа как в QtnProperty). Для каждого типа данных в фабрике регистрируем редактор и рисовальщик(либо делегата, который будет иметь методы создания редактора и отрисовки, в общем способы есть разные).

Примерный код, показывающий идею, представлен ниже.

```
class TypePainter;
class DelegateFactory;

class CustomDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomDelegate (QWidget *parent = 0) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                         const QModelIndex &index) const
   {
      QString name = typeNameForIndex(index);
      TypePainter  * painter = delegateFactory->createPainter(name);
      painter >paint(painter, option, index);
    }

   QWidget * createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const

   {
      QString name = typeNameForIndex(index);
      QWidget * editor = delegateFactory->createEditor(name);
      return editor;
   }

   //...

private:

   DelegateFactory * m_delegateFactory;
};

class DelegateFactory
{

public:
    DelegateFactory ();

   QWidget * createEditor(const QString & typeName);
   TypePainter * createPainter(const QString & typeName);

   //...

private:

   QMap<QString, QWidget *> m_editors;
   QMap<QString, TypePainter *> m_painters;
};


class TypePainter 
{

public:
    TypePainter ();

   virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,  const QModelIndex &index) = 0;
};
```

Получить имя типа можно из индекса разными способами. Либо через QVariant, но тогда придется регать кастомный тип в QVariant. Либо хранить имя типа в данных, и из индекса получать указатель на данные.

Имеет ли смысл так делать и есть ли другие варианты?